# MathJax(LaTex) equation shows in the CKeditor body area but not on the final webpage?

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using CKEditor module and have enabled MathJax option. When I use MathJax it works in the CKeditor and shows teh eqiation, but on the final display webpage instead just showing equations it is showing all code. What could be the reason and solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check Manage Display in your content type and ensure it's using the proper text format. I think Mathjax has to be at the bottom of the list as well in the format settings.

Comment: Well, If I go to content-type/Article and check the format of Body, Default, Plain text, Trimmed, Summary or Trimmed, <Hidden>. I checked all option but no change. For you second sentence, If I have understand correctly, I went to configuration/Text Formats/Filtered HTML and check all selection, there is no option which is related to MathJax. Then I went to Config/CKeditor/Advanced options/, and I checked selection of MathJax is clicked, IT is.

Comment: I guess you are talking about separat MathJax module. But CKeditor has its own MathJax plugin and it is issue with that. So no need to install separate MathJax module.

Comment: Apologies you're right. No idea then..